# Is there a way in go to dynamicaly gather instances of a given struct type?

Tags: go, reflection, garbage-collection, delve

I would like, at any stage in a program, to perform an operation on all instances of a struct defined in a given package. In order to do that, I have contemplated developping a function that gather those instances. But I haven't found anything yet.

To clarify my goal (following '@Muffin Top' and '@Volker' answer), I currently do this registration manualy into a pointer store present in each package. There are two problems with this approach, the registration is a mundane task and it is error prone.

To make my case clear, consider a package `foo` with one struct `Foo`. `Foo` has one `string` field `Name`. The package also defines two instances of `Foo` declared as `Foo1` & `Foo2`

```golang
package foo

type Foo struct {
    Name string
}

var Foo1, Foo2 = Foo{Name: "Foo1"}, Foo{Name: "Foo2"}
```

The `GetInstancesOfPkg` I am trying to implement would be called like in the below example. The operation to perform is just to print the `Name` field.

This is a working example but with a mockup version of `GetInstancesOfPkg`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "reflect"

    "github.com/thomaspeugeot/test-heapdump/foo"
)

func main() {

    s := GetInstancesOfPkg("github.com/thomaspeugeot/test-heapdump/foo")

    for _, instance := range s {
        // cast instance on foo.Foo
        if f, ok := instance.(*foo.Foo); !ok {
            log.Panic("Unknown Struct " + reflect.TypeOf(instance).Name())
        } else {
            log.Printf("Instance of Foo has name %s ", f.Name)
        }
    }
}

// GetInstancesOfPkg return a slice of instances of Struct defined in the package pkgPath
// --- this is the mockup verion ---
func GetInstancesOfPkg(pkgPath string) (interfaceSlice []interface{}) {

    var listOfFooInstances = []*foo.Foo{&foo.Foo1, &foo.Foo2}

    interfaceSlice = make([]interface{}, len(listOfFooInstances))
    for i, d := range listOfFooInstances {
        interfaceSlice[i] = d
    }
    return
}
```

For the solution, I know there is no such function in the `reflect` standard library or any other library I know of. However, I was contemplating :

- an algorithm that parses the entire program memory, identify each variable, get its type and gather those that match the struct type of the package. Since delve and heapdump do parse the entire memory and that delve can guess the variable type, I have a hunch that my desired function could be implemented. I have been trying to see how delve is doing or how heapcoredump is developped but this is a too big piece of knowledge to swallow for the desired goal.
- an alternative would be to add a pre-compilation step that modifies the abstract syntax tree (AST) by adding the registration each time there is a a variable initialisation.
- I am not even sure if this level of reflexion is possible with go (or if it is portable ?)
- Performance is not an issue, the program could be compiled with wathever flag necessary or the entire memory could be parsed.

Comment: The Go standard library does not provide a way to enumerate values of a given type.  What is the higher-level problem that you are trying to solve?  There may be a way to write some application code to solve that problem.

Comment: This higher level problem is that currently, I manually register all instances manually in a pkg store

Comment: Note that even the garbage collector might not ever see some instances of some type. Only the compiler itself knows. Your idea of using a pre-compilation step is the one that's the most promising, in terms of portability and reliability.

Comment: @torek, thank for the insight on the GC. I will try the pre compilation step, that will be fun to see the resulting code.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way in go to dynamicaly gather instances of a given struct type?

No.

You must redesign, e.g. by allocating the instances through a function which memorizes them.

Comment: This higher level problem is that currently, I manually register all instances manually in a pkg store. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: @thomas The answer is still No.

Comment: do yo mean, even with a perfectly cogency of delve, I could not program a runtime memory analyser ?

Comment: @thomas Everything can be done. The question is not "can this be done" but "can this be done in a portable, sustainable way". The answer is No. Go (the language) makes no promises about how stuff is laid out in memory and different compilers might do it differently, even from version to version. Just accept  No as the answer to your  question and move on.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I wanted to know if Go provide a theorical ground for my request and the answer is no. I shall expect a considerable hack/effort to get to it.

Comment: Hi @Volker, another issue I forgot to mention about the allocation of instances through a function (such as a `func NewFoo() *foo.Foo`is that some variable are staticaly defined in the package (as in the example above) with many parameters at compile time. I do not know how to do that with the `NewFoo()` function.

Comment: @thomas Register these instances manually. Or even better: Redesign. This seems to be a XY problem.

Comment: Hi @Volker, thank you for letting me know what is a XY problem. In this case, the X is as follow: My client wants to write his business logic in a package with no dependencies to an ORM or need to register his instances manualy. However, at some stage, I want to register the instances that were created to put them into a database. I do not see what I can redesign here but forget about my client requirement.

Comment: @thomas What your client wants is undoable (in a portable, sustainable way). Just because it would be nice if something would be possible doesn't mean it is possible. If your X problem is "my client wants to explain his business logic in spoken langauge and the computer should understand and record it" you simply cannot do X. There simply is no "I want" in Go.